# Поиск заданной области в окне

Tags: c++

В общем, такая задача:
Сделать окно и поместить в него некоторую невидимую область и сделать так, чтобы при приближении к этой области курсора некий сигнал усиливался.
Каким способом можно это сделать и какую библиотеку использовать?

Comment: О каком сигнале речь?

Comment: К примеру, WinApi, регионы, обработка перемещения мыши. А приближение - длина вектора из центра региона до курсора мыши. Про сигнал тоже недопонимание, но Вам виднее наверное.

Comment: Сигнал абсолютно любой, имеется в виду просто звук. Например какая-то музыка. Затихает и усиливается при приближении к области